# How to add Tooltip to Richtext Editor - UMBRACO 7

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Im trying to find a way to add button that will create a tooltip for the Content Editors

- I want to add button somehow to the richtext, that will open and able to write the bubble text when circle a word:

example:

[image]

is this possible or there is a similar way to to it?

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco uses TineMce as its rich text editor. If you can find or write your own TinyMce Plugin that has the function you desire, you can load that plugin into the umbraco backoffice
https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Reference/Config/tinyMceConfig/#plugins